# OpenSSL error when opening HTTPS web page

Tags: ruby, ssl, open-uri

My code:

```
require 'open-uri'
open('https://www.google.com')
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `block in connect'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:55:in `timeout'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `connect'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:306:in `open_http'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:776:in `buffer_open'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:203:in `block in open_loop'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `catch'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `open_loop'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:146:in `open_uri'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:678:in `open'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:33:in `open'
from C:/Users/Lap/Desktop/geocodin.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

What am I missing?

I'm running Windows 7 and I'm on public wifi if that matters. I set the Wifi connection as Public.

## EDIT

When I add `require "openssl"; OpenSSL.debug=true` after the first line, I get this error:

```
OSSL_DEBUG: IS NOW ON!
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800: warning: error on stack: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `block in connect'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:55:in `timeout'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `connect'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:306:in `open_http'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:776:in `buffer_open'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:203:in `block in open_loop'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `catch'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `open_loop'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:146:in `open_uri'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:678:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:33:in `open'
```

Comment: Try adding `require "openssl"; OpenSSL.debug=true` at the top of your code and see if that causes any additional errors/warnings to be printed.